# How do I fix this Glassfish-4 EJB(@RolesAllowed) lookup issue

Tags: security, glassfish, ejb, corba, iiop

I am trying to lookup a bean Deployed on different Glassfish instance. 
My app is running on another glassfish instance.

The EJB has @RoleAllowed("APPUSERS") annotation at class level.

I have created custom realm and JACC provider on both the instances.

When I try to lookup the Bean it gives NamingException and Corba No Permission error.